# warning: ignoring return value of 'system' c

Tags: c

In my program I put this code for instructs program to spawn a command. This can be used to start another program using a key in my program, such as to spawn firefox. Using program-command run_command "firefox" will have program call system( "firefox &" ).

```
    case RUN_COMMAND:
        if( arg ) {
            char commandline[ 256 ];
            snprintf( commandline, sizeof (commandline), "%s &", arg );
            if( cmd->screen ) {
                char message[ 256 ];
                snprintf( message, sizeof (message), _("Running: %s"), arg );
                screen_show_message( cmd->screen, message );
            }
            system( commandline );
        }
        break;
```

When I compile it give this error:

```
warning: ignoring return value of 'system', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

Comment: It's not an error; it's a *warning*. (That's why it's called "warning", rather than "error".) What's your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declared with attribute warn_unused_result \[-Wunused-result\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148134/declared-with-attribute-warn-unused-result-wunused-result)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that you shouldn't assume that `system` will always succeed. Your code becomes unreliable this way. Appropriate error handling should be in place.

Answer (score 16):

The warning means `You did not check the return value of system(...)`.
To avoid this warning, simply check the return value!

```
int systemRet = system(commandLine);
if(systemRet == -1){
  // The system method failed
}
```

This is, as `system` is not guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: Sometimes system returns -1, but actually succeeds.

Answer (score 6):

The library writers declared this function as `warn_unused_result`, because they feel it is important that you check whether the call succeeded.  One of your compiler flags told the compiler to check for this, so it's warning you about it.  The proper way to avoid the warning is to check the return value and handle errors appropriately (even if it's just printing an error message.  On a related note, you should check the return value of `snprintf` to ensure your buffer was big enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, it's a warning.

It's just saying you're not checking the return of the `system()` call.

> **Return Value**
>
> The value returned when the argument passed is not NULL,
> depends on the running environment specifications. In many systems, 0
> is used to indicate that the command was successfully executed and
> other values to indicate some sort of error. When the argument passed
> is NULL, the function returns a nonzero value if the command processor
> is available, and zero otherwise.

You shouldn't assume the call was successful, and treat failure.